# How can I add ".mp4" to the end of multiple files in a folder?

Tags: finder, filesystem, macos

I just received a bunch of videos (for editing) and something weird happened. I was told the files are .mp4, but when I received them they did not have a filetype assigned to them.

[image: Example]

I can add ".mp4" to the file name, which fixes the issue and allows my applications to recognize the files. Problem is, there are *a lot* of files.

Is there any way to easily add a ".mp4" to the end of all of the files at once? I'm willing to download an app for this if needed (Mac OS X 10.8.5)

Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason why you're still on 10.8.5? Yosemite adds, among other things, a batch renaming ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're comfortable with the command line you can try this in the terminal.app:

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "$i.mp4"; done;
```

Navigate to the directory with all of your files and run the above command.

Comment: Uhh… why are you piping text into `sh`? A simple command would really be sufficient.

Comment: This seems to meet the OPs needs. Feel free to post a better solution to help the OP.

Comment: If they are not comfortable with the terminal, they can navigate by opening the terminal, typing `cd ` (with a space) and then dragging the folder that contains the files into the terminal window and hitting return. Then run the `for` command...

Comment: Worked great! Also, thank you @beroe, I always have to look up the commands for navigating since I rarely use Terminal

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes the file extension is hidden, but it actually exists.

To show file extensions:

1. Choose Finder > Preferences, then click Advanced.
2. Select or deselect “Show all filename extensions.”

[Info](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13920?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)